# Transform or normalize nested JSON using lodash

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I am trying to transform a nested structure, using the library of lodash, I have achieved the expected result, but they are not functional if the structure changes, so I come to you to help me make more robust the function that transforms the JSON.

the initial structure looks like this

```
const data = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    },
    baz: {
      bar: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    },
    foo: {
      bar: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    }
  },
  bar: {
    baz: {
      bar: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    }
  },
  baz: {
    foo: {
      bar: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    }
  }
};
```

after being transformed

```
const transform = [
  {
    name: 'barfoo',
    results: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
  },
  {
    name: 'bazfoo',
    results: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
  },
  {
    name: 'foofoo',
    results: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
  },
  {
    name: 'bazbar',
    results: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
  },
  {
    name: 'foobaz',
    results: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
  }
];
```

The idea of the transformation is to join the nested key of the first level with the key of the parent node to generate the value of `name` in the new object and the value of the object in the 2 level as the value of `results`

for example for the first iteration of foo object in data

```
name = key(foo.bar) + key(foo)
results = value(foo.bar.baz)

name = 'barfoo'
results = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]

name = key(foo.baz) + key(foo)
results = value(foo.baz.bar)

name = 'bazfoo'
results = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]

name = key(foo.foo) + key(foo)
results = value(foo.foo.bar)

name = 'foofoo'
results = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
```

and so with the other objects that are inside data.

Comment: Why are you making us guess how the transformed data is obtained from the original? You've made it especially difficult because all the result objects are identical. Please help us out and explain where `barfoo` and the others come from and the logic behind the transformation.

Comment: So that's a little helpful, but it still doesn't clarify which object `barfoo` comes from. Is it the one at `data.foo.foo.bar`? `data.baz.foo.bar`? `data.foo.baz.bar`?

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark, I have updated the question, I hope it is understood a little better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the structure will ever vary, but I added a few extra test cases so you can see how this will behave in some additional scenarios.

```
const data = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    },
    baz: {
      bar: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    },
    foo: {
      bar: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    }
  },
  bar: {
    baz: {
      bar: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    }
  },
  baz: {
    foo: {
      bar: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
    }
  },
  a1: {
    a2: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
  },
  b1: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }],
  c1: {
    c2: {
      c3: {
        c4: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
      }
    },
    c5: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }]
  },
  d1: {
    d2: {
        d3: undefined
    }
  },
  e1: {
    e2: {
        e3: null
    }
  },
  f1: {
    f2: {
        // Ignored
    }
  }
};

function transformObject(object, name) {
    if (!name) {
        name = "";
    }
    return _.flatten(_.map(object, function(value, key) {
        if (typeof value === "undefined" 
            || value === null 
            || _.isArray(value)) {
            return {
                name: name,
                results: value
            }
        }
        var objectName = key + name;
        return transformObject(value, objectName);
    }));
}

transformObject(data);
```